# Why aren't these DNS records correct?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns

I'm hooking up my domain purchased on Godaddy with GCP where after DNS record check
my app will receive SSL certificate as well.

After following the instructions I see:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I know DNS changes can take all day for it to fully take effect but from experience I know it usually takes few minutes to fully propagate.

Any feedback is much appreciated.

**Update:**

[image]

[image]

**^ Another screenshot:**
it doesn't say the domain has been verified but anyway here it is:

**Added mapping for the naked domain as well:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm not getting any warnings yet getting 404 on my domain. External IP loads functional app.

Comment: How long did you wait? There is several async delay: DNS propagation, New check from Google Gloud, submission to let's encrypt to generate certificate, certificate installation and propagation on App Engine load balancer. It take at least 15 minutes when the DNS is correctly advertised.

Comment: It's been well over 2 hours now. Staff at Godaddy said to wait 48 hours but I know it never takes that long for it to take effect. There must be something wrong. Something not so obvious.

Comment: network stuff are never obvious!!! Did you have double check your domain name with this one set on App Engine custom domain?

Comment: `but I know it never takes that long for it to take effect` - that is a bad assumption. Once you have created the correct entries, it takes time to propagate. If you previously created bad entries, they could take even longer - research negative caching.

Comment: I changed the records only once. So wrong caching shouldn't have taken place. Maybe now it does though I can't tell either way.

Comment: You must map each custom domain. You only have `www` mapped. The naked domain is not setup.

Comment: @JohnHanley  Added mapping for the naked domain as well. Added screenshots to the question.

Comment: If the issue still persists, I would suggest [filing a case](https://console.cloud.google.com/support) so that [GCP Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) can take a deeper look.

Answer (score 0):

The first 4 records that you have in your screenshot are "google examples" that you can find at the bottom of this documentation: [Example DNS configuration](https://support.google.com/a/answer/48090?hl=en).

I don't think those are valid entries or IPs that you should be using in your DNS configuration. So, maybe removing them will help with your issue.

In this Guide you can find specific steps to setup your [Google Cloud DNS for your Godaddy Domain](https://www.siteyaar.com/setting-up-google-cloud-dns-for-your-godaddy-domain/#:%7E:text=Pointing%20GoDaddy%20domain%20to%20Cloud,your%20new%20nameserver%20type%E2%80%9D%20section).

Where you will find out, among other information, the Configuration entries you are looking for:

[image]

As well as how to Find your Godaddy domain(s) DNS zone Records

Comment: So I've followed the guide you've shared. I added update to my question. The app shows up when entering external IP but I'm getting just a blank page on www.mydomain.com or mydomail.com   so the networking is still off.

Comment: Values in the screenshot aren't real as I can't share it but it gives an idea what format and how well I've followed the tutorial.

Comment: being yours a custom domain, it seems that needs to be verified first as per this document: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#mapping_a_custom_domain_to_your_app, have you done that already?

Comment: It is added. It's not showing any green checkmark but since it's not giving me any warnings or errors I take it it is OK. I added relevant screenshot.